# Add a field to an object in an array mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongodb

I have the following schema in my mongo document:

```
{
  //more stuff
  arrayExample:[
    {
      //more stuff as well
      field1: "foo"
    },
    {
      //more stuff as well
      field1: "foo"
    },
    {
      //more stuff as well
      field1: "foo"
    },
    //...
  ]
}
```

What I want to do is add a field `id: ObjectId()` to *each* element inside the `arrayExample` so I could have something like follows:

```
    {
  //more stuff
  arrayExample:[
    {
      //more stuff as well
      field1: "foo",
      id: 1
    },
    {
      //more stuff as well
      field1: "foo",
      id: 2
    },
    {
      //more stuff as well
      field1: "foo",
      id: 3
    },
    //...
  ]
}
```

I tried to do this with an aggregation using **map** but it didn't work the way I did it. Is there a way to do this? thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatunately there is no built-in way in Aggregation to generate an ObjectId (for now).

But, you can make use of the `$function` Operator and write a custom code to do that.

> Note: The use of the `$function` method will impact performance significantly

> Also, the `$function` operator will work only on MongoDB Version 4.4 and above

The below sample code will work on Mongo Shell. Convert the `ObjectId()` part to auto ObjectId generator by a custom JS code in the function method.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "arrayExample": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$arrayExample",
          "in": {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              "$$this",
              {
                "$function": {
                  "body": "function() { return {'id': ObjectId()}; }",
                  "args": [],
                  "lang": "js",
                },
              },
            ],
          },
        }
      }
    },
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground Sample Execution](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5DeEjtazf8H)

Comment: I noticed there is a little problem with this.. the ObjectId is the same in all objects. I did this query through Compass

Comment: @RafDor, You are right, I didn't think about this earlier. Apologies. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you again!

Comment: Glad it helped you out. Do keep in mind that this is slower. Will update the answer if I come across a more optimized solution.

Comment: Don't worry just used it once to update some big documents. thx again